# How to create a char array from a double array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, char, double

I have a double array containing values that represent grades for a midterm, I need to create a char array with the same values but I need it to display letter grades. For example I need to go from {89.6, 73.9, 96.9} to {B, C, A}. Here is my code so far:

```js
  int numStudents = 60;
      int studNum = 1;
      double[] midtermGrades = new double[numStudents];
      Scanner grades = new Scanner(System.in);
   
      System.out.println("Here are the scores for the most recent test taken by your class:");
      
      
      for (int i = 0; i < midtermGrades.length; i++) {
         midtermGrades[i] = (60 + (double)(Math.random() * 40));
         System.out.printf("Student " + studNum++ + " : " + "%.1f\n", midtermGrades[i]);
      }
      
      double total = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < midtermGrades.length; i++) {
         total += midtermGrades[i];
      }
      
      double studAvg = (total / midtermGrades.length);
      System.out.printf("The average grade for your class was " + "%.1f\n", studAvg);
       
      int aboveAvg = 0;
                
      for (int i = 0; i < midtermGrades.length; i++) {
         if (midtermGrades[i] > studAvg) {
             aboveAvg++;
         }
      }
      System.out.println("There are " + aboveAvg + " students in your class who scored above the average.\n");
      
     
      
      char[] letterGrades = new char[midtermGrades.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < midtermGrades.length; i++) {
         letterGrades[i] = (char)midtermGrades[i];
               
   }
}
```

Comment: You need ranges. Eg. 75 - 85 is C grade. So you can check if the double value is in this range and assign the grade (using if - elseif ... - else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a different char array for that and specify a criteria for grading

```
char midtermgrades2 = new char[numStudents] ;
for(i=0;i<midtermgrades.length;i++)
{If(midtermsgrades[i]<100 && midtermsgrades[i]>80) 
Midtermgrades2[i]='A';
else 
//specify more conditions like this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use ASCII table. For example, the 10th place of 96.9 is `9` and the decimal values of character `A` and `J` is `65` and `74`, respectively. Therefore, you can subtract `74` by `9` to get the corresponding decimal value of character `A`. Following code snippet shows how to transform the `double` array into expected `char` array:

**Code snippet**

```
double[] midtermGrades = {89.6, 73.9, 96.9};
char[] letterGrades = new char[midtermGrades.length];
for (int i = 0; i < midtermGrades.length; i++) {
    if (midtermGrades[i] < 60) {
        letterGrades[i] = 'E';
    } else if (midtermGrades[i] >= 90) {
        letterGrades[i] = 'A';
    } else {
        letterGrades[i] = ((char)('J' - (int)midtermGrades[i]/10));
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letterGrades));
```

**Console output**

> [B, C, A]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You have to have a grade mapping based on marks. In the below example, I have the mapping as follows,

- marks > 90 - A grade
- marks between 80 & 90 - B grade
- marks between 70 & 80 - C grade and so on

```
char[] letterGrades = new char[midtermGrades.length];
for (int i = 0; i < midtermGrades.length; i++) {
     letterGrades[i] = (char)midtermGrades[i];
}
```

You should replace the above block in your code with the following code

```
char[] letterGrades = new char[midtermGrades.length];
for (int i = 0; i < midtermGrades.length; i++) {
        if (midtermGrades[i] >= 90) {
            letterGrades[i] = 'A';
        } else if (midtermGrades[i] >=80) {
            letterGrades[i] = 'B';
        } else if (midtermGrades[i] >=70) {
            letterGrades[i] = 'C';
        } else if (midtermGrades[i] >=60) {
            letterGrades[i] = 'D';
        } else if (midtermGrades[i] >=50) {
            letterGrades[i] = 'E';
        } else {
            letterGrades[i] = '-';
        }
}
```

Hope, this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is making a number that makes sense as a **char** !!!

Math.random() only produces a number between 0 and 1 as a decimal.
**The trouble** is Math.random() is a primitive data type as a double number AND static ! , also, a **number of a char is an "integer number"** corresponding a code page language charset symbol e.g. charset ISO_1152 is ASCII and has less than 100 symbols defined corresponding an integer number.

Java default english language charset is IS0_8859-1 and contains symbols alike UTF-8 from 0 integer to 255 integer of 'integer value".

If the result of Math.random() were rounded to an integer value, it would all simply have either 1 or 0 as the underlying number value.

```
double dblval = (double)Math.random(); // (double) syntax casts the "static" context out to a normal value
    int primaryconv = new Double(dblval).intValue(); // causes numeric rounding('narrowing' in the API docs) to an int
    char[] myconversion = new String((new Integer(primaryconv).toString())).toCharArray(); // calls toCharArray() on String object inside default encoding
```

Rather than use Integer , to narrow (round() the number to a long) with
Math.round(double) can be used and returns a "long" not an int.

```
double dblval = (double)Math.random(); // (double) syntax casts the "static" out (removes static context) to a normal value
String primaryconv = new Long((long)Math.round(dblval)).toString(); // note the EXTRA running cast to "long' to remove 'static' context
char[] myconversion = primaryconv.toCharArray(); // calls toCharArray() on String object inside default encoding
```

Answer (score 0):

If 3rd party libraries are an option and the overhead caused by boxing can be neglected, the simplest and cleanest solution is to use com.google.common.collect.RangeMap from [guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

```
    final RangeMap<Double, String> grades = ImmutableRangeMap.<Double, String> builder()//
    .put(Range.closed(90D, 100D), "A")//
    .put(Range.closedOpen(80D, 90D), "B")//
    .put(Range.closedOpen(70D, 80D), "C")//
    //so on
    .build();

System.err.println("99.9 -> " + grades.get(99.9));
System.err.println("77.8 -> " + grades.get(77.8));
```

This will yield the following result:

```
99.9 -> A 
77.8 -> C
```

The only thing you need to take care is that the ranges do not overlap.